# full outer join on two keys

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, full-outer-join

I am trying to do merge two tables on phone numbers so that if I find phone in either of the tables then join the rest of the fields as shown below.
Now there are scenarios where phone doesn't exist in both the tables. Then the table should join on email_id, so basically first check if phone matches if not then check for email id match. If none then drop the record.

```
select COALESCE(icici.phone, hsbc.phone) as phone,
    COALESCE(icici.email_id, hsbc.email_id) as email_id, city
from credit_card.icici
full outer join credit_card.hsbc on icici.phone = hsbc.phone
                or icici.email_id = hsbc.email_id 
    limit 10
```

But I am getting this error

> ERROR:  FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable or hash-joinable join conditions
>
> SQL state: 0A000

Is there a way to solve it, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could do a left join in two sub queries, with a union between them. Also, you say you want to match on phone, and if that doesnt match, then email. Your query looks for either, so you could conceivably get two matches from different rows. Is that what you want?

Comment: You can't refer to columns by number in a FROM or WHERE. 1 & 2 represent integer values in that query.

Comment: Learn what OUTER JOINs return: LEFT/RIGHT JOIN ON return INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left/right table rows extended by NULLs. FULL JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN ON, a WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a column with introduced NULL to be not NULL removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". Similarly for FULL JOIN ON. You have that.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  And your `where` clause makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can union the result of a left and a right join:

```
SELECT COALESCE(icici.phone, hsbc.phone) as phone,
    COALESCE(icici.email_id, hsbc.email_id) as email_id, city
FROM credit_card.icici
    LEFT OUTER JOIN credit_card.hsbc on icici.phone = hsbc.phone
                    OR icici.email_id = hsbc.email_id 
UNION (
    SELECT COALESCE(icici.phone, hsbc.phone) as phone,
        COALESCE(icici.email_id, hsbc.email_id) as email_id, city
    FROM credit_card.icici
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN credit_card.hsbc on icici.phone = hsbc.phone
                         OR icici.email_id = hsbc.email_id
    WHERE icici.id IS NULL
)
```

However, the right join may only contain the rows that were not found for any values from the left table. These rows are filtered out using `WHERE`, for example, by checking the primary key for `NULL`.

Comment: Please note that this is no complete full out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: what is     WHERE icici.id IS NULL? do u mean icici.email_id is null.. if so then why only in one part of union have u done so

Comment: That's what I meant by _for example, by checking the primary key for `NULL`_.

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select phone, max(email_id)
       maxCOALESCE(icici.phone, hsbc.phone) as phone,
    COALESCE(icici.email_id, hsbc.email_id) as email_id, city
from ((select phone, email_id
       from credit_card.icici
      ) union all
      (select phone, email_id
       from credit_card.hsbc
      ) 
     ) cc
group by phone,
         (case when phone is null then email_id end);
```